# Standard deviation of a dynamic (large) range? [excel]

Tags: excel, statistics

I need to calculate the standard deviation of this generator whenever it is at a steady state (i.e. the % response change is constant) so I can compare it to the Ideal Response. The only way I can think of is using a 64x nested IF statement to check is the value in column F has changed and offset the array. This is very crude and the range can be 600+ so it will not be accurate anyway.

Can anyone help me? I'm seriously out of my depth here.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK5YY.png]

Comment: Try STDEV function or one of it's variations, come back if it doesn't help.

Comment: The dataset is very large and I'm dealing with a dynamic range so I can't manually enter/autofill using stdev although I feel like I'm missing a simple way. I know I need to use STDEV in some form. I've seen some related questions use a combination of offset and countA but I can't apply that here as the % Response Change is always populated.

Comment: I can't use DSTDEV as I only want the values up until the next change in column I, not all values at that % response change.

Comment: If you aren't using something like macros it might be hard. A dirty way to do this would be have a cell that contains the addresses that you can use for a range. IIRC indirect can then be used https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: Interesting... How do I apply this to a range? Helper column? And then?

Comment: Been exploring this all morning and decided that I a macro is the way to go. Problem is I don't know where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction about how to return an array depending on when a value (i.e. column F) changes? I've been on Google for the last hour now and come up with nothing.